# vb.net pRO 2017 cannot build with a DLL that has function named 'WriteOnly' which is VB reserved word

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, managed

How can I work around this problem?

I need to interface to a DLL (InhecoMTCdll.DLL from Inheco.com) that exposes in its API the function name 'WriteOnly()', which is a VB.NET reserved word.
The problem then is that my VB.NET windows forms app gets a build error when I declare the API.

Is there anyway to work around this?  I don't have the source code for the DLL.  I tried JetBrains dotPeek to decompile, but could not see how to re-compile.

API of InhecoMTCdll.DLL .......................

public int FindTheUniversalControl(

```
int ID);
public void WriteOnly(string msg);
public string ReadSync();
```

My declaration of API in my VB.NET Pro 2017 windows app....

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Inheco_Thermoshake_interface

    Public Class NativeMethods

        ' Function within DLL:  
        ' Public int FindTheUniversalControl(int ID);
        ' which corresponds to VB.NET declaration:
        <DllImport("InhecoMTCdll.dll")>
        Public Shared Function FindTheUniversalControl(ByRef ID As Int32) As Int32
        End Function

        ' Need to re-program DLL with Inheco_WriteOnly because WriteOnly is VB keyword.
        ' public void WriteOnly(string msg);
        <DllImport("InhecoMTCdll.dll")>
        Public Shared Sub WriteOnly(ByRef msg As Byte())  <<<<<<< BUILD ERROR: "KEYWORD IS NO VALID AS AN IDENTIFIER"
        End Sub

        '  public string ReadSync();
        <DllImport("InhecoMTCdll.dll")>
        Public Shared Function ReadSync() As Byte()
        End Function

    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: Can you at least format your code properly?

Comment: Use the `EntryPoint` specifier on the `DllImport`.  EntryPoint has to match the actual DLL, but doesn't collide with VB keywords.  And then the method name can be anything legal.

Comment: Ben, can you please give an example of how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reserved word in VB.Net for function and variable names if you surround it with square brackets. For example:

```
Public Shared Sub [WriteOnly](ByRef msg As Byte())
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben.  I can't test it until hardware returns lab next week.  Crossing my fingers...